My threads are not running when running a flask app
Whenever I am trying to run a thread in my app.py containing my flask app, the thread does not run.
from flask import Flask, render_template
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)
run = True


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


def output():
    while run:
        print('run')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    output_thread = Thread(target=output())
    output_thread.start()
    app.run()


The thread output_thread should display 'run' in the console, but nothing is happening.
I have made multiple attempts to rewrite the code and tried various configurations, of running the thread, but none seem to work, I have also tried letting the thread do something else like write in pyautogui, thinking that the problem might have been with the console, without any luck.

if you run the app with python app.py (or whatever file you saved), it'll print the text. If you run it with flask run, it will not. Flask imports it as a module, so the name is not going to be __main__, and it will not enter the ìf` condition

You need instead output_thread = Thread(target=output).
